# Google Charts Timeline: How to print/pdf a complete chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I'm searching quite a while for an opportunity to print/pdf a complete timeline chart with repeating time-axis for every new page. Thanks for your help.

So I have to solve 2 steps to get the output:

**1) Only the part of the chart where the scrollbar belongs is shown in the export.**
I'm aware that the div height is responsible for that. See picture below:

[Pdf Output without changing the height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN0hW.png)

If I change the div height as example to 3000px I'll get the complete chart in the output. See picture below:

[Pdf Output after changing the height manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0N3J.png)

with that output I'm fine. But how to change the height of the timeline div on runtime? Since adding the height to as example 3000px from start on is no option for me.
I was thinking about adding the height via @media print {} in css. But it doesn't seem to work.

**Edit:**
To solve this I changed the timeline height of the div via JavaScript after clicking on the print button. To adjust the div to the max height of the content, I took the attribute height of the svg which contains the whole timeline. To get the correct svg I built in a condition (the svg element what you need can differ if there is a scrollbar or not). After changing the div height I needed to draw the chart again. After that I can export the whole timeline. Following that I changed the height of the div to it origin height and draw it again.

**I also edited the code, please see below.**

This solution may not be perfect, but it will do it job. Unfortunately some svg elements are cut of after page break.
To get a more fluent view you can disable the automatically created footer by adding the following css:
`@page { size: auto;  margin-bottom: 0;  }`

**2) Repeating timeline-axis on every new page**
I would like to have the time-axis on every new page on the pdf. Normally, the time-axis will be only printed once. So somehow I need to save the time-axis in a variable and put it on every new page. Wanted output (Photoshopped screenshot):

[Pdf Output repeating time-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHLwL.png)

Example code to work with:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['timeline'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
            var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
            dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
            for (let i = 0; i <= 21; i++) {
                dataTable.addRows([
                    ['Washington ' + i, new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
                    ['Adams ' + i, new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
                    ['Jefferson ' + i, new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]]);
            }

            chart.draw(dataTable);

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="printButton">Print</button>
    <div id="timeline" style="height:70%;"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#printButton").click(function () {

                var chartContainer = document.getElementById('timeline');
                if (chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[1] == undefined) {
                    var svg = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
                } else {
                    var svg = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[1];
                }

                var svgMaxHeight = parseFloat(svg.getAttribute("height")) + 60;

                $("#timeline").height(svgMaxHeight); //set Height to the complete Content height

                refresh(); //drawChart
                window.print();

                $("#timeline").height("70%"); //reset to default value
                refresh(); //drawChart


            });

        });


        function refresh() {

            drawChart();

        }

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the only solution i can think of would be to draw multiple charts. calculate the maximum number of rows that will print on a page, then draw multiple charts based on the number of rows in the data vs. the number of rows that will print on the page. if needed, you can hide the multiple charts, then display when the print button is clicked, and hide the original.

Comment: Hello WhiteHat, thanks for your response and efforts in Google Charts, you helped me to solve a lot of problems. I solved the first step please see my Edit. I don't know if your answear is an option for me, since the height of my rows differ from eachother and the building process is quite complexe. So I would need to count the height of each row and loop until the max page height is reached and then draw the next chart and loop again through. I was more thinking about saving the time-axis in a variable and then set a margin-bottom on every new page and insert the time-axis. Is this possible?

Comment: multiple charts would be difficult. it might be possible to copy or "clone" the svg elements that make up the timeline, then copy it to the margin area you mentioned. any solution here will be difficult...